# Two constraints with same base interface but both constraints cannot be the same

Tags: c#

Is it possible to has a class with two constraints from same base class but they can't be the same class. Example as below:

```
public interface BaseMessage { }

public class RequestMessage: BaseMessage { }

public class ResponseMessage: BaseMessage { }

public class BaseDocumentDefinition<B,C> where B: BaseMessage where C: BaseMessage //<-- At here how to define B cannot same with C?
{
   Document<B> RequestDocument { get; set; }
   Document<C> ResponseDocument { get; set; }
   // ^Here need to prevent RequestDocument and ResponseDocument end up being same class
}

//This will get correct compilation
public class DerivedDocumentDefinition: BaseDocumentDefinition<RequestMessage, ResponseMessage> { }

//This will also get success compilation, because **RequestMessage** valid for both constraint
public class DerivedDocumentDefinition2: BaseDocumentDefinition<RequestMessage, RequestMessage> { }
```

Comment: Is it a problem if the same type is used, or just that it's not anticipated to be useful? If the latter, you might consider creating a Roslyn analyzer to issue a usage warning.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever , yes it will be a problem in later implementation, like around sending request.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you include your own custom analyzers somehow in the solution (source control), or does it have to be deployed as a vsix to each development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible, but that is by design. With your constraint

```
class BaseDocumentDefinition<B, C> where B : IBaseMessage where C : IBaseMessage
```

you are basically saying that you need two types `B` and `C`, both of them providing all functionality specified in the interface `IBaseMessage`

So you want two types that can behave like a "base message". If that does not work for you, then you need to redefine your interfaces. If for example one of your "base messages" needs a method to provide a request and the other one a method to read a response, you'll have to split them into two interfaces, for example like this:

```
public interface IBaseMessage {   }

public interface IRequestMessage : IBaseMessage {
    dynamic GetRequestMessage(...);
}

public interface IResponseMessage : IBaseMessage {
    dynamic GetResponseMessage(...);
}

public interface IDocument<T> where T : IBaseMessage {   }

public class BaseDocumentDefinition<B, C> where B : IRequestMessage where C : IResponseMessage //<-- At here how to define B cannot same with C?
{
    IDocument<B> RequestDocument { get; set; }
    IDocument<C> ResponseDocument { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ehssan , thanks, this sounds like the best solution for me for time being.

Comment: If you want to avoid accidential use of the same class, this approach is fine. But if you want to avoid deliberate bad-usage, you would need base classes instead of base interfaces. The same class could implement both interfaces. But I still agree with this solution. Trying to avoid the consequence of someone who actively decides to write bad code is futile anyway :)

Comment: I thought you might be able to hack it by creating an ambiguous situation for the compiler somehow, such as having both `Compile(B b) { }` and `Compile(C c) { }` method overloads. Unfortunately compiler is too clever :/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the where constraints only allow positive assumptions as in "X is Y", they do not allow negative assumptions as in "X is not Y".

So no, what you want is not possible. You will need some base class or interface that positively defines the expected difference.

Comment: Hi @grek40 , yup this is the only solution I can think of for time being. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @grek40 said.

However, you can kind of force different types by throwing exception in the constructor. It is not intuitive but would solve your problem.

```
public BaseDocumentDefinition()
{
    if (typeof(B) == typeof(C))
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Types must be different.");
    }
}
```

Comment: But not hoping for this approach as the exception only thrown on runtime which the system already running into problem.

Comment: That's where testing comes into place.

Comment: On your example, it's more like we know there is high chance system running into error if someone code it wrongly and we only manage it later which I tried to prevent this kind of situation cause I can't control how others code. In @Ehssan 's example, it's forcing coder to comply with the contract which can minimize this kind of mistake. And  thanks for your suggestion, I believe it will be useful in near future. :-)

Comment: I understand your point. This was just to show that you can pull off this kind of approach, without making too many changes to the architecture, but by any means would I recommend using it.